# Jenkins Error: Failed with: Error: spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe

Tags: jenkins, gruntjs, intern

I am trying to build my intern test in Jenkins(slave) using grunt. The grunt files performs certain functions one of which is failing. This is what the grunt files looks like. These are intern tests. The error that I get is because it fails to start the sample. 
The error in the jenkins console

```
[4mRunning "unzip:sample" (unzip) task[24m
Created "./sample" directory

[4mRunning "exec:start-sample" (exec) task[24m
[31m>> [39mFailed with: Error: spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT
[33mWarning: Task "exec:start-sample" failed. Use --force to continue.[39m
```

This is the console where there was no error

```
[4mRunning "unzip:sample" (unzip) task[24m
Created "./sample" directory

[4mRunning "exec:start-sample" (exec) task[24m

[4mRunning "wait:45" (wait) task[24m
```

***GruntFile.js***

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
        grunt.initConfig({
            exec: {
                'start-sample': {
                   cmd: 'start serverstart.exe -z ../../sample',
                   cwd: '../../WEB-INF/bin64'
                },
                'stop-sample' : {
                    cmd: 'start serverstop.exe -n "Sample" -user abc -pwd abc',
                    cwd: '../../WEB-INF/bin64'
                }
            },
            unzip: {
                'sample' : {
                    src : '../../sample.zip',
                    dest : './sample'
                }
            }

}
```

Comment: for me it looks like that you have an npm issue // add --ignore-scripts may solve the issue.

Comment: can you run it from cmd line? all necessary env vars correct?

Comment: env var are correct.

Comment: Also looks like node_modules are installed as well